# VRML IndexedLineSet thickness

Tags: vrml

I want to increase the IndexedLineSet thickness here is my code:

```
geometry IndexedLineSet {  
    coord DEF Line Coordinate { 
        point [0 0 0, 0 0 0] 
    }  
    coordIndex [ 0, 1, -1 ] 
}
```

I have tried lineWidth but it doesn't work is there any other attribute I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as I understand it (it's been a long while) if you want to use an IndexedLineSet you can't control the thickness. There's no thickness attribute for an IndexedLineSet and the appearance is implementation dependent. You'd have to have boxes, or extruded circles/ellipses to get a thickness.